# Scroll UIPageViewController programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have difficulties to scroll programatically my `UIPageViewController` embedded in a main `UIViewController`, here is the architecture of my screen :

At the bottom of my screen I’m using `UIPageViewController` to display 2 controllers.

At the top of my screen I have a `UICollectionView` which is not part of the `pageViewController`. 
For some needs, I synchronized the scroll of the `collectionView` with the scroll of the `pagerViewController`.

So now I have a `pagerViewController` that is scrolling when user scrolls into my `collectionView`. I’m using : `pagerScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(...)` to do that.

My problem is that `UIPageViewController` uses its `gestureRecognizers` property to call its datasource methods properly. But when playing with `pagerScrollView.setContentOffset`, its dataSource methods are not called, so the next controller is not provided.

These are not called :

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
```

I tried to call `pagerController.setViewControllers`  in the `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` method, but the controller is immediately changed, the `UIPageViewController` don’t keep the controller that is being transitionned.

**My question is the following :**

Is there a way to tell the `UIPageViewController` which controller is next / before without losing the controller that is currently transitioned ? Or is there a way to fire datasource methods using the `setContentOffset` method on my pager ?

When scrolling into the `pagerViewController`, obviously everything is working well because its datasource methods are called.

Any idea?

Comment: If you have only 2 controllers, I'd suggest *not* using `UIPageViewController`. Instead, use a standard `UIScrollView`, add the 2 controllers as child VCs and add their views to the scroll view.

Comment: I end to resolve the problem by replacing the pager with a `UIScrollView`, and it's working well. I think it is not possible to achieve what I want with a `UIPageViewController`. 

Thank you @DonMag.